# peer.on('signal') is calling again when I addTrack(ex.screenShare track) - simple-peer

Tags: simple-peer

peer.on('signal') is calling again when I addTrack(ex.screenShare track) when a video call is going on then another peer connection is establishing
with this error

[image]

But the replaceTrack is working fine.I am not able to figure out
Can u please help me in solving these problem. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

From the [official documentation](https://github.com/feross/simple-peer) the syntax is `peer.addTrack(track, stream)`